# `gcloud logging read --format` json lines?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Does `gcloud logging read --format` have a [JSON lines](https://jsonlines.org/) output?

`json` seems to output pretty printed output that cannot be processed line by line as the stream starts and ends with a JSON array: `[]`

Line by line processing would be useful for large log streams.

Comment: Tools change over time. Therefore provide details on the problem you are having today.

Comment: @JohnHanley I have a massive log stream that I would like to watch and process each line as it arrives.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if the command works with the option `format = JSON`, then yes. I currently use that in a Node.js app on a `Google Cloud SDK 429.0.0` installation to parse logs.

Comment: I am asking if it outputs in this format instead of pretty printed https://jsonlines.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Google Kubernetes Engine or the App Engine flexible environment, you can write [structured logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/structured-logging) as JSON objects serialized on a single line to stdout or stderr. The Logging agent then sends the structured logs to Cloud Logging as the jsonPayload of the LogEntry structure.

Some fields in the JSON object are recognized as special by the Logging agent and extracted into the [LogEntry](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry) structure and can be used to set the following fields in the LogEntry.

- severity
- spanId
- labels (defined by the user)
- httpRequest

Because JSON is more precise and versatile than text lines, you can use JSON objects to write multiline messages and add metadata.Pretty-printing JSON will usually generate a number of "\n" within the JSON for better reading.

To read up to 10 log entries( limit can be according to our requirement) in your project's syslog log from the VM instances containing payloads that include the word SyncAddress and format the output in JSON format, run:

```
gcloud logging read "resource.type=gce\_instance AND logName=projects/[PROJECT\_ID]/logs/syslog AND textPayload:SyncAddress" --limit=10 --format=json
```

Comment: I am asking if it outputs in this format instead of pretty printed https://jsonlines.org/

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this need today, and while I didn't dig deep into the gcloud cli output options, jq could be used to do this if it works for your workflow.

Something like this:
`cat gcp_logs.json | jq -c  '.[]'`